# differences in async functions in c#

Tags: c#, asynchronous, task

I was reading about the async pattern in [C# in depth](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/161729134X), and I decided to take Jon's advice and decompile the async code to actually see what was going on. And I came across two scenarios that confused me a bit as to why they were different.

Consider these two functions:

```
public static async Task<string> GetValue(){
    int count = 0;
    count++;
    string g = "asdf";
    var r = Task.FromResult<string> ("hello");
    return g;
}
```

And

```
public static async Task<string> GetValue(){
    int count = 0;
    count++;
    string g = "asdf";
    var r = await Task.FromResult<string> ("hello");
    return g;
}
```

Now I'd expect the code to ouput the same IL being that they are both async functions so there needs to be a state machine. But to my surprise the C# compiler does create the statemachine in both cases follows all the same code as one would expect, except in the first code block it doesn't actually save any information in the machine. Where in the second it does store all the variables.

Is there a reason that the compiler decides to not save the variables in the state machine and expose two different code paths based on the `await` keword?

Answer (score 2):

The first one should have given you a warning about not really being async ("... will run synchronously") because there is no `await` in there.

So there is a state machine because you marked it `async` and it could be called with `await`.

But there is no information to keep because there is no `await` inside the method that would use it.

Comment: It just seems kind of strange that even though there is no await and the statemachine is created it just decides not to keep track of anything, I'd like to know why the compiler goes through all the hassle doing all the async code and then just ignore storing anything. I understand why the statemachine exists for capturing exceptions and what not, but not sure why it would skip saving things at all. Are there performance impacts or something else I'm not seeing?

Comment: From the outside it still is (looks) async. Why wouldn't the compiler implement the state-machine? It has to handle an await call somehow.

Comment: Again that makes sense I'm just wondering why there is a specific case of if(!await keyword) don't push anything into the statemachine why even have that branch

Comment: @dbarnes Because the `State Machine` will hold the persistence for your `async` method with the `await` operator.

Comment: @dbarnes - There is no `if(...)` in your code, I don't get your last comment.

Comment: If you look at the IL it is different so there must be some kind of branch logic in the compiler that says if there is something to await on then start loading those variables into the `statemachine`. if not then don't bother. My question lies in why there is a branch in the first place and not just always load everything into the `statemachine` regardless if there is something to await on or not.

Comment: That probably is an optimization. Turn it around: why would it load anything? And what would it load? I think the internal await(s) trigger that.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Thats what I would think too, but what are the costs of loading into the struct or a local variable on the stack? I'm really surprised that there would be need to optimize this. I was hoping for a more concrete answer.

Comment: Look at the answer from @PetSerAl.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the disparity stems from the lack of the `await` operator.  Without the `await` the compiler is treating your code as synchronous code. Which has no reason to utilize the `state machine`.

So in essence it creates the `state machine` as it expects `asynchronous` code, but you do not actually implement any code that is `async`.  Which keeps it as an empty container.

> The setup code initializes the state machine used to represent the
>   asynchronous method and then kicks it off using a call to the
>   secondary MoveNext method on the state machine. This state machine
>   type holds state for the asynchronous method, allowing that state to
>   be persisted across asynchronous *await points*, if necessary.

The State Machine holds your data in your second example because of the `await`.  This triggers the State Machine to persist the data through multiple `await points`.  Since the other example doesn't contain await, it remains empty.  It only created the State Machine because you decorated it as `async` though it really isn't.

A small excerpt from an [article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/hh456402.aspx) on the matter, hopefully this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Only variable, that visible by `await` expression need to be captured:

```
public static async Task Method() {
    int a=3;
    Console.WriteLine(a);
    {
        int b=3;
        Console.WriteLine(b);
    }
    await Task.FromResult(true);
}
```

For example, in code above `a` captured, `b` not captured. So, if you does not use `await`, nothing need to be captured.